# How to integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}dx$$

Can I substitute $x+1$ with $u$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $u=\sqrt x$ then $du=\frac1{2\sqrt x}dx\implies dx=2udu $ so

$$\int\frac{\sqrt x}{x+1}dx=2\int\frac{u^2}{u^2+1}du=2u-\int\frac2{u^2+1}du=2u-2\arctan u+C$$

Comment: How get this?
$2-\int \frac{_{\:}^{\:}2}{u^2+1}\:du$

Comment: You don't, because an error was made. $\int \frac{u^2}{u^2+1} du = \int (1 - \frac{1}{u^2+1}) du = u - \int \frac{1}{u^2+1} du$. My first step comes from polynomial long division.

Comment: @Ian thanks, so difficult to see the question and know what to do...how do i know i should u=x^1/2 and not something else

Comment: @problematic this comes with the experience. You need to practice a lot of integrals to get confident with the guess of the right substitution. If you want to practice a bit [here](http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/menue3dd.htm) you can find a lot of integrals to compute, which also give you hints on what is the right substitution to do if you don't see it straight away.

Comment: @problematic Because square root signs suck, and a good rule of thumb is to try to get rid of them.

Comment: Also, Sami—for completeness, maybe you should substitute $u=x^2$ back into the answer, to have it in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is 
$$
2 \sqrt{x} - 2 \tan^{-1}\sqrt{x} + C
$$

How could a wrong answer (which is easily checked by differentiating) get 3 upvotes?

Comment: You are right; correction accepted.

Comment: @MarkFischler thanks

Comment: @ale thanks~~~~~~

Comment: As your parachute  answer got an upvote a wrong answer could get upvotes:-)@MarkFischler